# C - Pupulate (get) data with a function. Best via reference or copy (in micro controller enviroment)?

Tags: c, 8051

I am currently programming a 8051 µC in C (with compiler: Wickehaeuser µC/51) and so that, I am thinking which way is the best, to pupulate a structure. In my current case I have a time/date structure which should be pupulated with the current Time/Date from an RTC via SFRs.

So I am thinking of the best method to do this:

- Get the data via return value by creating the variable inside the function (get_foo_create)
- Get data via call by reference (get_foo_by_reference)
- Get via call by reference plus returning it (by writing I think this is stupid, but I am also thinking about this) (get_foo_by_reference)

The following code is just an example (note: there is currently a failure in the last print, which does not print out the value atm)

**Which is the best method?**

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char foo;
    unsigned char bar;
    unsigned char baz;
}data_foo;


data_foo get_foo_create(void) {
    data_foo foo;
    foo.bar = 2;
    return foo;
}

void get_foo_by_reference(data_foo *foo) {
    // Read values e.g. from SFR
    foo->bar = 42; // Just simulate SFR
}

data_foo *get_foo_pointer_return(data_foo *foo) {
    // Read values e.g. from SFR
    (*foo).bar = 11; // Just simulate SFR

    return foo;
}


/**
 * Main program
 */
void main(void) {
    data_foo struct_foo;
    data_foo *ptr_foo;

    seri_init(); // Serial Com init
    clear_screen();

    struct_foo = get_foo_create();
    printf("%d\n", struct_foo.bar);

    get_foo_by_reference(&struct_foo);
    printf("%d\n", struct_foo.bar);

    ptr_foo = get_foo_pointer_return(&ptr_foo);
    //Temp problem also here, got 39 instead 11, tried also
    //printf("%d\n",(void*)(*ptr_foo).bar);
    printf("%d\n",(*ptr_foo).bar);


    SYSTEM_HALT; //Programm end
}
```

Comment: Do you need the extra return functionality of `get_foo_pointer_return` as compared to `get_foo_by_reference` for some reason? If you are not "chaining" the functions or not returning some kind of error it seems redundant. I would avoid `get_foo_create`, as it is involving (potentially) large data to be passed around.

Comment: No I do not need. It was just a thought, like "May be its for some reason the better pattern, to always return a value from a getter"

Comment: BTW, it's more like "setter" or even "constructor" if we make analogies..

Answer (score 1):

On the 8051, you should avoid using pointers to the extent possible.  Instead, it's generally best--if you can afford it--to have some global structures which will be operated upon by various functions.  Having functions for "load `thing` from address" and "store `thing` to address", along with various functions that manipulate `thing`, can be much more efficient than trying to have functions that can operate on objects of that type "in place".

For your particular situation, I'd suggest having a global structure called "time", as well as a global union called "ldiv_acc" which combines a uint_32, two uint16_t, and four uint8_t.  I'd also suggest having an "ldivmod" function which divides the 32-bit value in ldiv_acc by an 8-bit argument, leaving the quotient in ldiv_acc and returning the remainder, as well as an "lmul" function which multiplies the 32-bit value in ldiv_acc by an 8-bit value.  It's been a long time since I've programmed the 8051, so I'm not sure what help compilers need to generate good code, but 32x32 divisions and multiplies are going to be expensive compared with using a combination of 8x8 multiplies and divides.

On the 8051, code like:

```
uint32_t time;
uint32_t sec,min,hr;

sec = time % 60;
time /= 60;
min = time % 60;
time /= 60;
hr = time % 24;
time /= 24;
```

is likely to be big and slow.  Using something like:

```
ldiv_acc.l = time;
sec = ldivmod(60);
min = ldivmod(60);
hr  = ldivmod(24);
```

is apt to be much more compact and, if you're clever, faster.  If speed is really important, you could use functions to perform divmod6, divmod10, divmod24, and divmod60, taking advantage of the fact that divmod60(h+256*l) is equal to h*4+divmod60(h*16+l).  The second addition might yield a value greater than 256, but if it does, applying the same technique will get the operand below 256.  Dividing an `unsigned char` by another `unsigned char` is faster than divisions involving `unsigned int`.

Comment: @supercat Currently I have a global structure. But because I consumes more memory and pollutes the "global namespace" I wanted to populate the structure like with a call by reference (which seems the best meanwhile). Or is this a very uncommon pattern? Plus for my understanding it is more flexible and more useably in other projects.

Comment: @supercat Also what do you mean with ldivmod/ldiv_acc? ldiv_acc reminds me to assembler (which I do not know).

Comment: @TickTacJoe: There's a global union called `ldiv_acc`, which I described earlier.  The `ldivmod(x)` function computes `ldiv_acc % x` while it performs `ldiv_acc /= x;`, returning the former result.

Comment: @TickTacJoe: Pointer arithmetic on the 8051 is very inefficient.  Not totally impossible, but code which uses objects in `data` storage will often run much faster and take less space than code which tries to operate on objects accessed via pointers.

Comment: @supercat With this compiler I do not have such an union.

Comment: @supercat I know what you are saying. Because pointers run in XRAM, right? But anyway I have to use the "large memory model", because I have so much variables that it must run in XRAM anyway. BTW: the compiler throws a warning:  Warning: function 'get_foo_create()' is returning structure by value

Comment: @TickTacJoe: If memory serves, the 8051 compiler can efficiently handle returns of structures that occupy exactly one byte, two bytes, or four bytes.  Three bytes is not a preferred size.

Comment: @supercat From which compiler do you talk? In general? Because, I am using Wickenhäuser µC/51

Comment: @TickTacJoe: I used an Archimedes-branded Keil compiler back in the day.